# Can't login to Azure AD v2 account with outlook account using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to set up Azure AD v2 from http://aka.ms/aaddevv2 using https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-nodejs (master branch @ b752987b7367fc92692ac538e1fc24cb400d0fbc), however I can't seem to log in with accounts created outside of the user who created the the app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?deeplink=/appList.

On the apps.dev.microsoft.com end, I have:

- the Application ID, and have created a password which I've used in the `clientID` and `clientSecret` respecitively in the [config.js](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-nodejs/blob/master/config.js) file.
- Added `http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return` under `Redirect URLs`
- Have `User.Read` for the `Delegated Permissions` section

Is there anything else I need to set up? Am I missing something in the code?

The error I get when logging in with accounts outside of the setup account is:

> Sign in
>   Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS50020: User account '[email]' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application '[clientID]' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to use the v1 endpoint maybe? You have v2.0 in your `identityMetadata`?

Comment: Yep, it says `identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/techsamlabs.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'` in [config.js](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-nodejs/blob/master/config.js#L3). I was thinking I might have gotten my tenant id wrong, but then it did work when I logged in with the owner's account.

Comment: Right, you used a tenant id there. That means the authority specifying the tenant will be used. It won't allow personal accounts. You have to use common :)

Comment: Perfect! That works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the identity metadata URL so that it allows personal accounts.

For example:

```
identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

Instead of `common` you can use `consumers` if you want to only allow personal accounts.